# Metro UI controls not showing on form instead show as a component

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am using MetroUI in windows form in c#. If I drag some control of metroUi then it does not appear on window while some are appearing, like button and textboxes are not displaying and become a component. But combobox is working fine. How can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance to all those who gonna help.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following steps to solve it.

1. Install MetroModernUI via NuGet Packages
   [image: here]
2. Open your project folder and check this path \packages\MetroModernUI.1.4.0.0\lib\net. It has 3 .dll files.

   MetroFramework.Design.dll

   MetroFramework.dll

   MetroFramework.Fonts.dll
3. Add these 3 files to your project reference

[image: here]

[image: here]

If this does not solve the problem, it is recommended to restart VS.

Comment: I tried this by MetroFramework.Design and MetroFramework.Fonts are not being added, it says.  there are no components in "\packages\metromodernuu\1.4.0\lib\net\MetroFramework.Design.dll" that can be placed on toolbox.

Comment: You may have some misunderstandings about my answer, I suggest you check whether the "Reference" contains these three dlls, not the toolbox.As in the third step above.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem just now, i tried to re-download the nuget package, and the metro UI controls is not showing in the toolbox I even check the reference and restart the visual studio it didn't work. What solved my problem is I reboot my computer and it showed. My conclusion is that, this is some kind of a bug since all of my work suddenly don't have any metro UI controls.

Comment: maybe it was cache problem ?